# Juniper QinQ same port for customer as provider

Tags: juniper

Is it possible to use a single interface as both the provider port and the customer port for a QinQ setup on a Juniper EX 4200 switch?

I have a set of switches "on a stick" attached to the network. I want to use this ae0 to take in a number of C-VLANS (10,20,30) but then encapsulate them as the S-VLAN (1000) and send the newly minted S-VLAN packets back out port 1000. Is it possible?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
set interface ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members all

set vlans thousand dot1q-tunnelling customer-vlans 10-30
set vlans thousand vlan-id 1000
set vlans thousand interface ge-0/0/1.0
```

?